# Recorded VBA macro throws "Autofilter method of Range class failed" error when filtering dates

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a sheet with a table in it. In the leftmost column are dates and I want to make a macro which filters a certain date.

So I tried recording a macro, this is what the recorder made:

```
Sub datefiltertest()
'
' datefiltertest Makro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$242").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "1/4/2023")
End Sub
```

But when I clear the filter and run the macro, it throws "Autofilter method of Range class failed" error. Why?

I tried looking for an answer and people recommended using Criteria1, changing the range to "Selection", running "ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False" first etc etc but none of it worked.

What baffles me the most is that I have a larger macro that uses the date filtering and it was working fine up until last year. Now it just crashes on the autofilter line. It's incredibly frustrating, please help.

Comment: How are all the cells in column A formatted, are they date, text, general, etc ?

Comment: The same happens on my end. If you're looking for the `4th January`, try `"2023/1/4"` or `"2023-1-4"`. `If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` will clear any previous filters.

Comment: @CDP1802 they are formatted as a date in a format that only shows day and month (1st of December would be "1.12". I tried changing the filter to Criteria1:="1.12" and that worked but I hoped I'd make the macro independent of the date's format but apparently that's not going to be possible.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions? The format has nothing to do with it. The underlying value is what counts i.e. if it's a date.

Comment: It might be possible to make it independent, what is the 2 for ? Is is only one date , between 2 dates or an array of dates ?

Comment: @CDP1802 The documentation states: *The second criteria (a string). Used with Criteria1 and Operator to construct compound criteria. Also used as single criteria on date fields filtering by date, month or year. Followed by an Array detailing the filtering Array(Level, Date). Where Level is 0-2 (year,month,date) and Date is one valid Date inside the filtering period.*

Comment: @VBasic2008 OK thanks, how does that differ from just `Criteria1:="1/4/2023"`

Comment: @CDP1802 In that it works. `Criteria1:="1/4/2023"` doesn't work on my end neither does `Criteria1:="2023/1/4"`. The macro recorder returns the exact code OP has posted although my system date format is d.m.yyyy i.e. I am filtering on 4th Jan which the code is suggesting with `1/4/2023`.

Comment: @CDP1802 Sorry for bothering you, but is your suggestion with `Criteria1` working on your end, or is it just something you remember used to work? Could you try my suggestion and share some feedback? It's the code OP posted except for the `yyyy/m/d` format. It should by kind of universal.

Comment: @VBasic I hate date format problems ! I didn't get Criteria2 when I recorded macro but my short date format is dd/mm/yyyy. I got this to work `Criteria1:="=" & DateSerial(2023, 4, 1)` for 1 Apr. I guess the = makes it a number compare rather than text.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work (I have noticed the equal sign). I think that If your date separator is a dot and the date format is d.m.yyyy then you can use `Criteria1:="4.1.2023"`. Yeah, I think not. It worked, but now it doesn't. The Criteria2 version still works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251179/discussion-between-cdp1802-and-vbasic2008).